# Display items in columns dynamically?

Tags: css

I'd like to display a list of items in multiple columns without having to specify the number of columns, and just let the browser add more columns so that all items fit.

I tried to adapt [this article](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=27f87), but the items are just listed as a long, one-column list:

```
<head> 
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        ul.columns {
          float: left;
          width: 12em;
          margin: 20px 0 1em;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
        }

        li.columns {
          float: left;
          width: 6em;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
        }
    </STYLE>    
</head> 

<body>

<ul class="columns">
    <li class='colums'>test</li>
    <li class='colums'>test</li>
    <li class='colums'>test</li>
    <li class='colums'>test</li>
    <li class='colums'>test</li>
</ul>
```

Any CSS expert could tell me what's wrong with the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert, but "columns" is mis-spelled...

```
<li class='colums'>
```

Technically, your `<li>`s do not need a class.  You can use this selector instead...

```
ul.columns li {
  float: left; 
  width: 6em; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
}
```